# Android MediaController sync with video state

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I have a MediaController `mc` and VideoView `videoView` which are linked as follows:

```
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

But, I also want to play/pause the video by clicking the video. So, I add:

```
    //Play/Pause the Video on Clicking Video
    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                videoView.pause();
            } else {
                int stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

The code works fine. But, when I click the video, the video pauses. But, the MediaController icon for `play/pause` is not changed. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling mc.show(0) in your onTouch() method.